# Collect Price values High[0] to High[50] mql4

Tags: mql4, mql

I was creating a for loop that looks for mean of price within a set array of 50. the difficulty I am having is with the collection and storage of High[0] to High[50] (Low[0] to Low[50]) data for the mean equation M= (Total Value/nbars)

I was trying to follow C++:

```
float arithmeticMean(float [], int);
int main()
{
    int n, i;
    float arr[50], armean;
    cout<<"Enter the Size (maz. 50): ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"\nEnter "<<n<<" Numbers: ";
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        cin>>arr[i];
    armean = arithmeticMean(arr, n);
    cout<<"\nArithmetic Mean = "<<armean;
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
float arithmeticMean(float arr[], int n)
{
    int i;
    float sum=0, am;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        sum = sum+arr[i];
    am = sum/n;
    return am;
}
```

And I attempted to resize the buffer and store price values, but this isn't correct, ideas?:

```
{
int d = High[50]+Low[50];
double rb[],armean;
for(int s=-1; Close[s]<d; Close[s++]) //Array Iteration Loop Forward BarsToCheck
{
double Meansize = ArrayResize(rb,s);
double sum = Meansize+rb[s];
}
armean = sum/d;
}
```

Comment: You should not add tags which are not relevant. Your question refers to MQL4 but you have tagged MQL5 which is a different language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are really getting things confused, just keep it simple. Also remember that arrays are 0 based, therefore, if you want to count 50 items you will run from 0 to 49.

```
double total=0.0;
int count=50;
for(int i=count-1; i>=0; i--) total+=High[i];
double mean=total/count;
```

Comment: this is how much confusion I go through as I learn to code MQL: I was told to follow this structure to code mean https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/430138. I find it extremely difficult to source simplified knowledge about coding if I can't learn it myself through text books and other modes. Could I keep in touch with you regarding some coding advice?

Comment: If you have any further problems, just post the questions here on stackoverflow and then everyone can benefit from the answers.

Comment: Hi Paul, would you be able to take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/73628495/19793575